# NGINX Multiple Sites on Same Host

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm fairly new to Nginx. When I connect to my server I would like to have multiple sites on the same host. Each site is a separate docker container being server by an Nginx image, serving an Angular app. I'm using proxy pass because we will eventually be leveraging the load balancer function.

For example when I go to `<host name>/teamsite` it should be proxy to the upstream server `http://teamsite`.

The following code works perfectly using just 1 site, navigating to .

```
upstream teamsite {
    server localhost:8200;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    location / {

        proxy_pass          http://teamsite;
        proxy_redirect      off;

        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

        gzip on;
        gzip_types          text/plain application/xml application/javascript;
        gzip_proxied        no-cache no-store private expired auth;
        gzip_min_length     1000;

    }

}
```

When I try to add in the /teamsite it stops working.

Example:

```
upstream teamsite {
    server localhost:8200;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    location /teamsite {

        proxy_pass          http://teamsite;
        proxy_redirect      off;

        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

        gzip on;
        gzip_types          text/plain application/xml application/javascript;
        gzip_proxied        no-cache no-store private expired auth;
        gzip_min_length     1000;

    }

}
```

It looks like Nginx is looking for the files in `localhost:8200/teamsite/index.html` instead of `localhost:8200/index.html`. Any ideas why the extra `/teamsite/` is being added to the upstream server?

Thank you for your help.

Edit:

I did try the following config:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    location /teamsite/ {

        proxy_pass          http://localhost:8200/;
        }
}
```

Now when connecting to `<host name>/teamsite` the reverse proxy is throwing connection refused errors. The webserver version of Nginx is not showing any connections or errors. I am able to connect to the webserver version of Nginx from the server and my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

This answer https://serverfault.com/a/725433 shows the proper syntax for what are you trying to do and shows how the url rewriting works.

Comment: Yea so I tried that, the reverse proxy is now throwing connection refused errors when trying to connect to the web server. The request does appear correct from the logs. The Nginx web server logs do not show any errors/requests. I am to pull the files directly from the Nginx web server on y local machine. New config listed is now in the original post.